# Es posible usar más de 2 box-shadow?

Tags: html, css

En principio se que usar más de uno en CSS u otro no es posible debido a que según el orden en que se encuentren todos se cancelarían hasta que solo quede uno el cual se aplica. En todo caso de no ser posible me las arreglaría por mi mismo pero quisiera saber que podría hacer ya que quisiera conservar el box-shadow con inset además de que quisiera usar un que se muestre en el exterior.

Nota:

No necesariamente busco usar el box-shadow 2 veces en el mismo elemento.

No puedo usar más de un div ya que en realidad el como lo tengo echo crearía más problemas con las posiciones y la apariencia del texto.

Si, se que es más sencillo usar un background-image pero quisiera saber otra opción en el caso hipotético de que no fuese posible.

```css
.element {
    box-shadow:inset 0px -20px 10px -10px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow:0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

[NoEsDeImportancia] {
  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
  left:45%;
  background-color:gray;
  width:30px;
  height:20px;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border:5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" align="center" NoEsDeImportancia>
Hey
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si miras en [la documentación de box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), verás que te dicen que puedes poner múltiples efectos separados por comas.

Para tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```css
.element {
    box-shadow:inset 0px -20px 10px -10px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

[NoEsDeImportancia] {
  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
  left:45%;
  background-color:gray;
  width:30px;
  height:20px;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border:5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" align="center" NoEsDeImportancia>
Hey
</div>
```